# Incrementing a parameter of type INT in dynamic SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic-sql

I'm trying to increment a parameter set within my script by 1 every loop of my while.

This is an example of what I'm doing within my script:

```
DECLARE @I AS INT;
SET @I = 0;

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @SQL =
'WHILE '+ Convert(Varchar, @I)  +' < (SELECT statement here...)
BEGIN
  SET '+ Convert(Varchar, @I) +' = '+ Convert(Varchar, (@I + 1))'
END'
```

There is a lot more to this script but this is the relevant part. I understand that `'+ Convert(Varchar, @I) +'` is just going to concatenate the value of @I to the string, but could anyone offer any advice in how I can make it so that the value of @I is incremented by 1.

Currently when executing the sql, the set command will end up like the following:

```
SET 0 = 0 + 1
```

where as I need it to change the actual variables value for the next loop.

Is this even possible?

Comment: Is your heart set on loops? try explaining the original problem and maybe there will be a better way. I always feel like there is a problem when loops appear in sql.

Comment: Also do not convert integers to varchar's, you will run into troubles

Comment: @Snowlockk I know an alternative method, but this script is only going to be ran once on any "clean" system. I want to reduce the amount of times I hit the server  in this process so that's why I've made it a loop.

Comment: @balaji thanks for the heads up :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the '@I' as a variable in your query:

I'm trying to increment a parameter set within my script by 1 every loop of my while.

This is an example of what I'm doing within my script:

```
 DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @SQL = '
    DECLARE @I AS INT;
    SET @I = 0;    

    WHILE  @I  +' < (SELECT statement here...) +
    '
    BEGIN
      SET  @I = @I + 1
    END'
```

Comment: Must declare the scalar variable "@I".

Comment: *feeling embarrassed*  Oh wow... it was really that simple? Thank you!

Comment: I'll +1 when I unlock the privilege :3